How Do I Automate Importing Text Files into Notes?
When I open a pdf file in Notes it creates a very nice note in my default 'notes' folder that I can use for reference. However, when I open a txt or rtf file in notes I have it opens a small pane requiring me to select 'import' and then it puts a not so pretty note in an Imported Notes folder which I then need to move. And if I happen to import another txt or rtf file I get yet another new folder titled Imported Notes 1. Now I have to move two notes and delete two folders. Is there a better way?
